# How to solve problems with offline map display?

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

There is one problem: I made it using maperitive tiles with the required scale of 12-15 (so that the map is available offline), then the task was to connect the resulting offline map to this project: https://github.com/ds4es/real-time-units- gps-tracking (the project is based on transferring data using kafka from a csv file, which contains latitude ,longitude time, to a map with the leaflet plugin, to display the real-time movement of markers on the map), however, this did not work, apparently some are required - something http requests, not just a link to tiles. I want to note that a similar way of writing: `file:///home/jonh/openstreetmap/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` worked in another project, but unfortunately not in this situation. Attached images below

[image: 1st figure]

The 1st figure shows the state of affairs when adding an offline map ( line: `MAP_URL_TEMPLATE=' Tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`) and, as we can see, only moving labels are displayed, and the map itself is not displayed;

[image: 2nd figure]

2nd figure Shows the state of affairs when the online map is used, i.e. constantly need internet to display it;

[image: 3rd figure]

The 3rd picture shows the console, where, before the red line, an offline map was used (`Tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`). And after the red line, I changed the address to the online map again: `'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'` and the map started showing up all over again.
How can I connect an offline map? Thanks for answers :)

Comment: So where are your offline tiles, exactly? What happens when the browser tries to request `http://127.0.0.1:5001/Tiles/0/0/0.png`?

Comment: @IvanSanchez I did as you wrote: "404 Not Found ". I also wrote the path to an existing photo, I still got a 404 error (127.0.0.1:5001/Tiles /11/1628/1058.png )

Comment: @IvanSanchez I will assume that the python code does not accept local files without raising the server. In my practice, I came across a similar task (loading offline maps) in javascript, but in JS it was possible not to raise the server to display the map.

Comment: Re-read https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#static-files